# How to check filename in if condition that calls function in php

Tags: php, function, if-statement

i'm calling multiple functions from a function...as per my scope i want to call a specific function from parent function as per file that calls that function...

```
function dispcategories() {
    include ('database/connection.php');

    $select = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM categories");

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select)) {
        echo "<table class='category-table'>";
        echo "<tr><td class='main-category' colspan='2'>".$row['category_title']."</td></tr>";
        dispsubcategories($row['cat_id']);
        dispsubcategoriesstate($row['cat_id']);
        echo "</table>";
    }
}
```

From dispcategories i want to call dispsubcategoriesstate() if and only if file updatestate.php calls dispcategories()...if any other file calls dispcategories() than it should not call to dispsubcategoriesstate()...
Hope everyone get the question it is possible to check file name threw if condition or not who calls the function

Comment: Why not just pass a boolean argument to your function that tells the function what to do?

Comment: I advise you to add an optional argument to your function.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i didn't get your suggestion?can u explain it more

Comment: Andy explained it well in his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Including a file is just like typing it into your source code.  You can use the magic constant `__FILE__` to determine the current file, but this won't tell you what file the calling function was written in.

I'd suggest that you should rather pass a parameter to your function and then call the subroutine based on that.

Declare your function like this and replace the line `dispsubcategoriesstate($row['cat_id']);` with the block shown below

```
function dispcategories($fetchSubCategories = false) {
    // your code goes here
    if ($fetchSubCategories === true) {
        dispsubcategoriesstate($row['cat_id']);
    }
    // the rest of your code goes here

}
```

When you call it from the file where you do not want sub-categories you will call it like you do now:

```
dispcategories();
```

Whenever you want it to fetch the subcategories you can pass the parameter through like this:

```
dispcategories(true);
```

I'm using an optional function argument and if this is confusing you should read the [manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php).

Comment: Thanks for reply but when updatestate.php calls dispcategories than it should not call dispsubcategories....it must call only dispsubcategoriesstate function...and other file only able to calls dispsubcategories

Comment: @visananiraj - Just modify the code to fit your needs. This is still the way to go.

Comment: both dispsubcategoriesstate and dispsubcategories do same work only change is dispsubcategoriesstate displays sub categories and also allows user to update status of categories...now i've implemented andy's solution but when i call from updatestate.php with true value it will display categories two times

Comment: then use `if ($fetchSubCategories === true) { dispsubcategoriesstate($row['cat_id']); } else { dispsubcategories($row['cat_id']); }`

Comment: @MagnusEriksson   i've done it some other way but still thanks for your reply i also can use this way as alternative....Thanks again